# Detect my windows store app view has been snapped or filled

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps

I am developing windows store app in c#/XAML.Since it is mandatory for my app to support the snapped view of windows 8 so that it passes certification.I have decided to show a static image or add an scrollviewer to my pages like most of other apps do when snapped. The thing is I want to know how to determine whether my app has been put into snapped or filled view? I want to detect it and I want to add a horizontal scroll to my app pages so that user can scroll even though it is in snapped or filled view. I glanced this [Tutorial](http://marcominerva.wordpress.com/2013/10/16/handling-visualstate-in-windows-8-1-store-apps/),but I need more guidance for applying my logic.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ApplicationView.Value` [property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/hh701658) to determine the current view state of your application and `WorkflowViewStateService.ViewStateChanged` [event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activities.presentation.view.workflowviewstateservice.viewstatechanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to subscribe for changes to the view state.

Comment: Well what if i added scrollViewer on every page of my app and set its scroll mode as auto. So it automatically brings on the scroll when app is snapped and filled. Will it pass the windows certification?

Comment: I can't see any reason why it shouldn't pass. But to be safe use [Windows App Certification Kit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh694081.aspx), this way you can detect if there are any issues with your application.

Comment: Scrollviewer is not prohibited, but it's better to add some logic to support snapped view, because it's cool :)

Answer (score 0):

The usual method is to create two layouts(grids) on the same page that bind to the same data, one for full screen and one for snapped(you can also create more if you want to support portrait vs landscape). By default the full screen layout is Visible and the Snapped is Collapsed. Listen for the SizeChanged event and then show/hide the correct layout depending on the new size.